# Begineers learning to Fibonnaci in R. Ratios

Tags: r, for-loop, fibonacci

I am a begineer trying to learn R. I have the following code to find the 20 first Fibon

```
Fibonacci <- numeric(20)
Fibonacci[1] <- Fibonacci[2] <- 1
for (i in 3:20) Fibonacci[i] <- Fibonacci[i - 2] + Fibonacci[i - 1]
print(Fibonacci)
```

This works and gives me the first 20 numbers. However I want to try to find the ratio between a Fibonacci number and the previous Fibonacci number for every element n in {3,..,20}. How would this simply be done? I have tried

```
Fibonacci <- numeric(20)
Fibonacci[1] <- Fibonacci[2] <- 1
for (i in 3:20) Fibonacci[i] <- Fibonacci[i - 2] + Fibonacci[i - 1]
print(Fibonacci)
q<-c(Fibonacci)
lists<-c()
for(i in 3:20)
list[[i]] <- q[i]/q[i-1]
print(list)
```

Where my idea is to make a vector with the Fibonacci numbers (q) and the make a list with all the altered elements to find the ratio and then print them out. Any suggestions?

New poster here and extremly new to R

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty nice already. This should work, when you initialize your vector called list properly with: `list<-c()`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems fine. In general, there is no need to reinvent the wheel though. One advantage of R is the use of packages. For this, I recommend the `numbers` package to create the fibonacci numbers and then use `lag` to create the ratios, i.e.

```
fib <- numbers::fibonacci(20, sequence = TRUE)
rel.fib <- fib/lag(fib)
rel.fib <- rel.fib[-1]
> rel.fib
 [1] 1.000000 2.000000 1.500000 1.666667 1.600000
 [6] 1.625000 1.615385 1.619048 1.617647 1.618182 1.617978
[12] 1.618056 1.618026 1.618037 1.618033 1.618034 1.618034
[18] 1.618034 1.618034
```

---

**Extra**

By writing `numbers:::fibonacci` you can even see the source code of the function that generates the fibonacci numbers. This is useful as it confirms your strategy and gives best practices in terms of R programming from which you can learn a lot.

```
> numbers:::fibonacci
function (n, sequence = FALSE) 
{
    if (!is.numeric(n) || length(n) != 1 || floor(n) != ceiling(n) || 
        n < 0) 
        stop("Argument 'n' must be a single integer >= 0.")
    if (n <= 0) 
        return(0)
    if (n == 1) 
        return(1)
    if (n > 78) 
        warning("For 'n > 78' not exactly representable in R as integer.")
    if (sequence) {
        if (n == 2) 
            return(c(1, 1))
        fib <- numeric(n)
        fib[1:2] <- c(1, 1)
        for (k in 3:n) {
            fib[k] <- fib[k - 1] + fib[k - 2]
        }
    }
    else {
        if (n == 2) 
            return(1)
        f1 <- 1
        f2 <- 1
        for (i in 1:(n - 2)) {
            t <- f2
            f2 <- f1 + f2
            f1 <- t
        }
        fib <- f2
    }
    return(fib)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000017c1c9dbed0>
<environment: namespace:numbers>
```

Comment: But I am getting a point too much with this way. n is in the elements from 3,..,20 i.e the first point 1.00000... should be removed. How do I do that?

Comment: By writing `rel.fib <- rel.fib[-1]`. I edited my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Vectorize the operation, no need for loops.

```
Fibonacci[-1]/Fibonacci[-length(Fibonacci)]
# [1] 1.000000 2.000000 1.500000 1.666667 1.600000 1.625000 1.615385
# [8] 1.619048 1.617647 1.618182 1.617978 1.618056 1.618026 1.618037
#[15] 1.618033 1.618034 1.618034 1.618034 1.618034
```

To see why it works, print the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: But I am getting a point too much with this way. n is in the elements from 3,..,20 i.e the first point 1.00000... should be removed. How do I do that?

Comment: @mathstudent23 If `result` is the result of the division in the answer, it's `result[-1]` you want.